# App Screen is moved down (on iOS device)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Steps to reproduce:

1. I opened social login form(vk)
2. Change phone rotation.
3. Click "Cancel" on form and back to app.
4. App screen is moved down.

My AS3/Adobe Air app on ios with settings

```
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>
<visible>true</visible>
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
```

and

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

I'm using Flex SDK 4.6.0.23201, and Air 17.0.0.123

Can I disable rotation or something?

Answer (score 0):

You application displayState is changed to NORMAL, you can handle it while app activated. In flex we have activate, event when app is bring back from some other application. You can set again to fullscreen by

```
systemManager.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

It's decision.

Comment: Is this the answer to the question or more info for your original post? If this is the answer, please mark it as so by selecting the green checkmark. If it's more info, it should be added as an edit to your original question. Thanks!